# An example of a disjunctive 0,1-simple lattice which is neither 0-simple nor 1-simple.

Tags: lattice-orders

This is a follow-up to my previous question: [A 0-simple lattice which is not a 0,1-simple lattice.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4516237/a-0-simple-lattice-which-is-not-a-0-1-simple-lattice). Following the terminology of the previous question, I define a disjunctive 0,1-simple lattice to be a lattice $L$ with more than one element such that for every non-constant homomorphism $f$ of $L$, either $f$ preserves the bottom element of $L$, or $f$ preserves the top element of $L$. (But some homomorphisms may preserve the top but not the bottom, or vice versa). Is there an example of such a lattice which is neither 0-simple nor 1-simple?

Comment: The 3-element chain.

Comment: @KeithKearnes I know this is another question, but is that the only example? I suspect that is the only example up to isomorphism. Is it true, or are there others? Perhaps there are in fact infinitely many non-isomorphic examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In response to a comment on the original question, I am going to describe some classes of examples. First, let me restate the question:

A bounded lattice $L$ of more than one element is $0$-simple if, whenever $\theta$ is a proper congruence on $L$, the $\theta$-class of $0$ is $\{0\}$. $L$ is $1$-simple if, whenever $\theta$ is a proper congruence on $L$, the $\theta$-class of $1$ is $\{1\}$. $L$ is disjunctive $0,1$-simple if, whenever $\theta$ is a proper congruence on $L$, either $0/\theta=\{0\}$ or $1/\theta=\{1\}$. The question asks if every disjunctive $0,1$-simple lattice is either $0$-simple or $1$-simple. The answer is No.

**Example 1.** (From the comments) Let $L$ be the $3$-element chain. This  is a disjunctive $0,1$-simple lattice that is neither $0$-simple or $1$-simple.

**Example 2.** (A slight generalization) Take two nontrivial, simple, bounded lattices $B$ and $T$ (= bottom and top). Let $L$ be the lattice obtained from $B$ and $T$ by stacking them vertically and identifying the top element of the bottom lattice $B$ with the bottom element of the top lattice $T$. This is a disjunctive $0,1$-simple lattice that is neither $0$-simple or $1$-simple. If $B=T=$ the $2$-element lattice, then this stacking leads to the $3$-element chain. This explains why Example 2 is a generalization of Example 1.

**Example 3.** (A different kind of generalization) Let $S$ be a nontrivial, simple, bounded lattice. Let $L$ be the sublattice of $S\times S$ that is the graph of the order relation $\leq$ of $S$. This  is a disjunctive $0,1$-simple lattice that is neither $0$-simple or $1$-simple. If $S$ is the $2$-element chain, then the graph $L$ of the order relation on $S$ is the $3$-element chain. This explains why this example generalizes Example 1. However, if $S$ is a simple lattice of more than two elements, then this kind of example is not obtained by stacking two simple lattices so it is different than Example 2. In the case where $S=M_3$ is the $5$-element simple lattice, this construction yields the $0,1$-disjunctive lattice in this picture
[image]

**Example 4.** (A generalization of each of the preceding examples)
Let $B$ and $T$ be two nontrivial, simple, bounded lattices. Let $L$ be any sublattice $L\leq T\times B$ containing $(\{0\}\times B)\cup (T\times \{1\})$, but not containing any pair of the form $(1,b), b\neq 1$, or $(t,0), t\neq 0$. This  is a disjunctive $0,1$-simple lattice that is neither $0$-simple or $1$-simple, and this construction includes all of the earlier examples.

Here is why Example 4 answers the question. If $L$ is constructed from $B$ and $T$ as described, then the fact that $L$ contains $(\{0\}\times B)\cup (T\times \{1\})$ implies that $L$ is a subdirect product of the simple lattices $T$ and $B$. By the congruence distributivity of lattices, the only congruences on $L$ are the equality relation $\Delta$, the total relation $\nabla$, and the kernels $\eta_T$ and $\eta_B$ of the coordinate projections onto the factors $T$ and $B$. The three proper congruences are therefore $\Delta, \eta_T$ and $\eta_B$. To show that $L$ is a disjunctive $0,1$-simple lattice that is neither $0$-simple or $1$-simple, observe that

1. $\{(0,0)\}/\Delta = \{(0,0)\}$
2. $\{(0,0)\}/\eta_B = \{(0,0)\}$
3. $\{(0,0)\}/\eta_T = \{0\}\times B$
4. $\{(1,1)\}/\Delta = \{(1,1)\}$
5. $\{(1,1)\}/\eta_B = T\times \{1\}$
6. $\{(1,1)\}/\eta_T = \{(1,1)\}$

By Item 3, $L$ is not $0$-simple. By Item 5, $L$ is not $1$-simple. By all six items, $L$ is disjunctive $0,1$-simple.